# Recognize arbitrary file extensions in R?

Tags: r

I'm writing a function in R that will take the path name of a folder as its argument and return a vector containing the names of all the files in that folder which have the extension ".pvalues".

```
    myFunction <- function(path) {
        # return vector that contains the names of all files
        # in this folder that end in extension ".pvalues"
    }
```

I know how to get the names of the files in the folder, like so:

```
    > list.files("/Users/me/myfolder/")
    [1] "myfile.txt"               
    [2] "myfile.txt.a"     
    [3] "myfile.txt.b"    
    [4] "myfile.txt.a.pvalues"
    [5] "myfile.txt.b.pvalues"
```

Is there an easy way to identify all the files in this folder that end in ".pvalues"? I cannot assume that the names will start with "myfile". They could start with "yourfile", for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at `?list.files`.  You want the `pattern` argument.  `list.files(path='/Users/me/myfolder', pattern='*\\.pvalues$')`

Comment: That's awesome, I have always used substring and was satisfied with that this is way better. +1

Comment: @user1440196 You're very welcome and welcome to SO.  If I've answered your question, please mark it as such with the check mark so that others can see that the question doesn't need further attention.